# How to convert %uXXXX code to plain text in python?

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

I have string like '%u0E1E%u0E1A%u0E40%u0E08%u0E2D%u0E02%u0E27%u0E14%u0E40' which I want to convert into plain text 'พบเจอ' 
I tried using function ord() and chr() as follwos

`chr(ord(u'\u0E1E'))` which will give palin text.

```
split_list = encoded_string.split('%')
for i in range(1,len(split_list)):
    split_list[i]= '\\'+split_list[i]
split_list
['', '\\u0E1E', '\\u0E1A', '\\u0E40', '\\u0E08', '\\u0E2D', '\\u0E02', '\\u0E27', '\\u0E14',.....]
```

Now when I am converting this to plain text with following loop

```
for i in range(1,len(split_list)):
    split_list[i] = chr(ord(u''+split_list[i]))
```

Getting following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-5ab6fb196276> in <module>
      1 for i in range(1,len(split_list)):
----> 2     split_list[i] = chr(ord(u''+split_list[i]))

TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 6 found
```

Please help me to resolve this Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a string where the backslash representation usually used to represent non-ascii characters has been replaced by a percent-sign based convention.

The solution is to replace the precent signs with backslashes - as you have tried - then encode to bytes and decode from the [unicode-escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) codec.  The result will be a Python `str`.

```
>>> s = '%u0E1E%u0E1A%u0E40%u0E08%u0E2D%u0E02%u0E27%u0E14%u0E40'
>>> # Encode to latin-1 as it won't lose any information.
>>> result = s.replace('%', '\\').encode('latin-1').decode('unicode-escape')
>>> result
'พบเจอขวดเ'
>>> # Result is longer than we expected
>>> expected = 'พบเจอ' 
>>> result == expected
False
>>> expected in result
True
>>> result.startswith(expected)
True
```